# Extract data from kCBAdvDataManufacturerData using Android BLE Apache-Cordova

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I developed an app under Apache-Cordova platform on Android, I want to broadcast data through kCBAdvDataManufacturerData, I sent 0000000 as a test, when I scanned on the app, I had:

> “SEMtMDgAAAAABzAwMDAwMDAAAAAAAA==”

Which really doesn't make sense to me since even if

> kCBAdvDataManufacturerData

is Base64, I should get the 7 same chars cuz I sent 7 zeros, can you kindly help me on how to decode the

> kCBAdvDataManufacturerData

I also scanned the same BLE device using an IOS app from which I got the

> <...730303030303030...>

which is reasonable since there are 7 '30' representing 7 '0'

Comment: I solved my self using atob()

Comment: If you like make an answer to your on question. Maybe with some sourcecode.

Comment: The codes are too simple I think, readers at this post can just refer to 64base encoded data encoding and decoding